# Can't print capital letters or brackets with pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I have this problem where if I try to simulate the pressing of caps, brackets or underscores it gives me an *a*.

This is roughly the code

```
obj = "Some text (other things)"
keyboard.type(obj)
```

Edit: I'm using pyhton 3.7.1 and pynput 1.4.2, on a Mac

Comment: So it types "aome text aother thingsa" instead?

Comment: Exactly. I can't figure out why

Comment: What happens if you try to directly type other characters with `keyboard.press()` and `keyboard.release()`?

Comment: Same thing, I also tried to take those characters out ad write them while "pressing" shift but only works with caps

Comment: What, exactly, are you typing *into*?  Have you tried anything else as the destination, such as TextEdit?

Comment: I've tried on word, TextEdit, SublimeText and even Google searchbar, but there are always _a_ s

Answer (score 0):

You can do it verifying the keycode

`keyboard.KeyCode(char='[')`

like this